# C/C++ comma operator puzzles me. Language lawyers?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I came across this bit of code in an example from the Boost documentation:

```
std::vector<int> input;
input += 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;
```

How cute. Boost has a template for operator+= that takes advantage of the fact that the comma is, under most circumstances, an operator. (Wisely, C++ does not allow a hackist to overload "*operator,*".)

I like to write cute code too, so I played around some with the comma-operator. I found something that looks weird to me. What do you think the following code will print?

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int i;
    i = 1,2;
    std::cout << i << ' ';
    i = (1,2);
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

You guessed it. VC++ 2012 prints "1, 2". What's up with that?

[Edit: I should have been more precise. Should have said C++ does not allow operator "," in a list of int's to be overloaded. Or better yet, nothing. The ',' operator can be overloaded for classes and enums.]

Comment: Err... the comma operator *can* be overloaded...

Comment: In fact if operator `,` couldn't be overloaded, boost wouldn't be able to do that neat trick.

Comment: @JanHudec: If you mean *horrific* trick... :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**CASE 1:**

`i = 1,2;`

`=` has higher precedence than `,`

hence, `1` is assigned to `i`.

Since assignment evaluates to an `lvalue` in `c++`,(evaluates to `rvalue` in `c`) it becomes `i,2` which evaluates to`2` (refer NOTE)

**CASE 2:**

`i = (1,2);`

`()` has higher precedence than `=`

`expressions` or `operands` separated by `,` operator evaluates to the value of the last `expression` or `operand` hence, `2` is assigned to `i`

---

**NOTE**

a `comma expression` like `33,77,x,y,z` is evaluated from **left to right**.

The result of such comma expression is the value of **rightmost expression** .

Examples

```
Consider, int z=100; 
then
1,4,5; //evaluates to 5
1,100,z+100; //evaluates to 200
```

Comment: +1 for clear and concise explanation of the operator. Perhaps it should also be mentioned that the `,` operator has left-to-right precedence and as such, chained usage `x, y, z` will return the right-most operand `z`.

Comment: Well duh. This is kind of embarrassing to a guy who once wrote a C parser. I have forgotten much. Not that that's a bad thing

Comment: @Anirudha: ... and that was a mistake. It **groups** left to right (which only matters if you are overloading it), but since it's not a sequencing point, saying it **evaluates** that way is confusing, since the arguments will be evaluated in any order the compiler happens to like today.

Comment: @JanHudec The comma operator is a sequence point.  The expression to the left, and all of its side effects, are sequenced before the expression to the right.

Comment: @Anirudha Stop while you are ahead. It is not clear to me what the last example adds. I hope not to sound ungrateful. You got the green check mark.

Comment: @JiveDadson 
the expression `z+100` is evaluated to `200` and then `200` is returned..That was what I wanted to add

Comment: @JamesKanze: Oops. Yes, of course, you are right. It is sequence point.

Comment: @Anirudha I do not know what alternative there is to consider for z+100 other than 200. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: @JiveDadson what it should return then..?

Comment: You should maybe say that `operator,` has specifically the lowest precedence *of all operators* for a reason. :)

Comment: In C, an assignment expression does not produce an `lvalue`, it's an `rvalue`.

Answer (score 5):

Simple: "=" has higher precendence.

```
i = 1,2;
```

Is like (i=1),2, meaning the result of the expression is 2 but it's discarded.

```
i = (1,2);
```

The result of (1,2) is 2.

EDIT: this might be so things like

```
for (i=0, j=0; ...)
```

work as expected.